# On finding the domain of a function with several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the function as following:
$$f\left ( x,y \right ):= \sqrt{\frac{x^{2}-2xy+y^{2}-10x+8y+20}{2x-x^{2}-y^{2}}}$$
Find its domain algebraically and then sketch its domain in the $xOy$ plane.
The first step I took in doing so is to consider two possible cases:

$1^{\circ}$

$$x^{2}-2xy+y^{2}-10x+8y+20\geq 0 \wedge 2x-x^{2}-y^{2}> 0$$

$2^{\circ}$

$$x^{2}-2xy+y^{2}-10x+8y+20\leq 0   \wedge  2x-x^{2}-y^{2}< 0$$

However, I am afraid that first inequality in  both cases can only be solved using numerical methods. Using the Desmos graphing calculator I get that the interesction region for case #1 is just the open region bounded by the circle in the denominator:

[image: Intersecting region]
And for case #2, I suppose, the intersection is just an empty set. Can anyone show a purely algebraic method on how to solve the inequality from the numerator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually given that your domain is some part of the plane limited by two quadrics, as you correctly identified, you may want to (or have to) describe these quadrics (center and radius for a circle, focal point etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "can only be solved by numerical methods". It seems to me that you're done. The domain can be described in terms of the circle and ellipse that you have already found. I don't see what else you can do.

Comment: What I meant is that that you can't find a nice closed form for the expression in the numerator like you are able to do in the denominator.

Comment: I guess I don't see any fundamental difference between the numerator and the denominator. They are both quadratics, so they both describe conic section curves. One of the curves happens to be a circle, but that's not really anything very special.